# Pandas Function pd.to_datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert a list of dates from Month/Day/Year to just Month and Day. So going from 6/2/1989 to just 6/2. Below is the line of code I thought would work.

`Time = pd.to_datetime(listofdates,  format = "%d%m", exact = False)`

and my output is something like "1900-06-02". I was hoping to just get Month and Day by its self. The problem arises when I go to plot the data and 1900 shows up on the x axis. I just want Month on the major x-axis and Day on the minor x-axis. So I was wondering on how to remove the 1900 either from the x axis or from the output data itself? I am using "plot_date()" to plot my date data on the x axis.

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of demonstrating the solution here, let's assume that your dataset looks like this:

```
In [84]: df
Out[84]: 
         date
0  2014-01-05
1  2014-06-09
2  2015-10-23
3  2015-12-21
4  2013-09-30

In [85]: df.dtypes
Out[85]: 
date    object
dtype: object

In [86]: df['formatted_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

In [87]: df.formatted_date = df.formatted_date.dt.strftime('%m-%d')

In [88]: df
Out[88]: 
         date formatted_date
0  2014-01-05          01-05
1  2014-06-09          06-09
2  2015-10-23          10-23
3  2015-12-21          12-21
4  2013-09-30          09-30
```

I hope that helps!